# Get value from dropdown to display table nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I am learning nodejs and mongodb. I am using expressjs and mongojs for the backend and ejs for the front end of my application. What I want to do is the user will select from the drop down to view a list of classes available and the list of classes will show in a table. For example, if the user selects all, all of the classes in the database will show in the table. I am not sure how can I get the value from the drop down menu and display the data from mongodb in a table form. This is what I have so far and I was getting this error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

admin.js

```
router.get('/showclass', function(req, res) {
   res.render('showclass');
});
router.post('/showclass', function(req, res) {
    var selectValue = req.body.table;
    if(selectValue == 'all') {
         console.log('All is selected');
         db.classes.find().forEach(function(err, doc) {
            if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.send(doc);
                res.render('showclass');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

ejs

```
<%- include('includes/header') %>
<%- include('includes/navbar') %>

<form method="post" action="/admin/showclass">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <label>Show Table By:</label>
  <select>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="recent">Recent</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <tr>
      <th>Class Name</th>
      <th>Class Time</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Instructor</th>
      <th>Maximum Students</th>
      <th>Brief Description</th>
      <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Data</td> 
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td><a href="editclass">Edit</a>/Delete</td>
  </tr>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</table>
</form>

<%- include('includes/footer') %>
```

Comment: the error you're getting is caused by your res.send command followed by the res.redner command. You can only respond to a request once.
Also, I would recommend you to read about ejs templating [link](http://ejs.co/)

Comment: Because of calling 'res.send()' and 'res.render()' sequentially, you get the error. If you want to send data to your EJS you can pass the parameters as an object like res.render('showclass', {param1: "test"})

Comment: Thanks, I'll read that link and update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.send` and `res.render` both do same thing, they send back response to users, you can't use both of them, remove `res.send(doc)` and pass your data to `render` method .

```
router.get('/showclass', function(req, res) {
   res.render('showclass');
});
router.post('/showclass', function(req, res) {
    var selectValue = req.body.table;
    if(selectValue == 'all') {
         console.log('All is selected');
         db.classes.find().forEach(function(err, doc) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.render('showclass', { doc: doc });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

take a look at [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render)

Comment: So, after I send the doc, in the html file, I can use doc.whatevervalue?

Comment: @NasimAhmed yes you can

Answer (score 0):

You can not call both `res.send` and `res.render` for the same request.

You can pass context to the `render` function in the second argument:

```
res.render('showclass', doc);
```

---

Reference:
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html